# symfony - calling an action from another action

Tags: model-view-controller, symfony1, action

i have two different actions in two different modules, and i need to execute one of them inside the other.

consider the following actions:

```
//first module
class module1Actions extends sfActions {

     protected function function1Form(sfWebRequest $request, sfForm $form) {
       //i need to call a function from module2 in here to do sth but i don't need any view to be returned.
       //but i need some variables to be returned by the second action
     }
}

//second module
class module2Actions extends sfActions {

     protected function executeSth(sfWebRequest $request, sfForm $form) {
       //Do Something in here and return some values.
     }
}
```

as i said i need to execute an action and get some values from it but i don't know how to call it. it's in a different module . can i access it ? how? and how i get the values back?

thanks.

Comment: You can't. This will break the MVC pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how you get those values, these are the best paths:

1. If you get them via operations on a record or a table, move the code into the model layer, and call that from both your actions
2. If you get them some other way (like processing user input), create a utility class in your `lib` folder, and add it there as function, and call that from both your actions

This way you prevent code duplication, and still don't break the MVC separation of concerns.

Comment: could you please tell med how can  you call and execute a lib file?

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a third method for doing this to Maerlyn's answer. Its useful in a couple of limited situations to prevent duplicating code, but to also not break a proper MVC design by moving the wrong code the the model layer.

- Store the values to be sent/and/or returned in the myUser class then use the `$this->forward()` call to run the relevant action without causing the browser to make another request.

Note that $this->forward() immediately halts the action you call it from and the template for the forwarded action will be the one displayed.